# Is it good Flutter practice to add a method to for rendering a widget with the data from that class?

Tags: class, oop, flutter, dart, methods

I am using class instances to hold data , within the widget tree I provide a function to render the data to a widget. Rather then calling the function within the widget tree would it be better to make this function a method within the given class?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, don't forget to go through the website [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also, don't forget to share your code to make it easier.

Comment: In my opinion , choosing from a state management approach ( Provider, BLoC, Redux or some other ) will be better. Read through [Making sense of all those Flutter Providers](https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-) or other state management references.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good practice to mix UI and business logic.

In flutter it's really easy to mess up your code since you write both your business logic and UI code in Dart language. But it depends on you to follow this path, which will definitely make you're application hard to maintain and scale, or try to decouple your business logic from your UI. This makes it really easy to add new features and also debug your application as it scales.

For doing this you can search about different architectures, like Clean architecture, MVC, etc, which would help you not only to decouple your UI from your business logic, but also to decouple your business logic to different layers that would make your code even more maintainble.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations!

Comment: You're welcome! If you found them helpful, I'd be happy if you accept the answer.